# How can I align button vertically in nav bar?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I'm practicing creating a website, and am currently trying to replicate [this site](https://pixelicons.com/). At the moment I am working on the navigation bar, but I am unable to vertically align the button vertically in the nav.

```css
.header {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 40px 20px;
}

.header h1 {
  background-color: yellow;
  float: left;
}

.header h1 img {
  display: block;
}

.header__nav {
  background-color: aqua;
  float: right;
}

.header__nav li {
  float: left;
  height: 38px;
}

.header__nav li a {
  padding: 0 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 38px;
}

.contents {
  background-color: green;
}

.footer {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<header class="header clearfix">
  <h1>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://pixelicons.com/wp-content/themes/pexelicons/assets/pic/site-logo/logo.png" alt="Logo"></a>
  </h1>
  <nav class="header__nav">
    <ul class="clearfix">
      <li><a href="#">View icons</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Buy now</a></li>
      <li><button class="menu">menu</button></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<section class="contents">
  contents
</section>
<footer class="footer">
  footer
</footer>
```

[My working image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kh6vM.png)

I wanna align the top-right button of the nav bar vertically. I know this can be solved using `display: flex;`, but I wanna solve it another way. Is there a proper way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though your solution using `display: flex`seems perfectly fine to me, you could fix it using `vertical-align: middle;` and `display: inline-block` on all of the items (the two links and the button)

Comment: Can you explain why your solution works?

Comment: @HaramBae yes: display: inline-block is used to position all elements in a horizontal line to each other while keeping a block-like behavour (setting width/height, margins etc.) and "vertical-align" is for positioning elements in certain ways vertically.
If this works for you let others know by marking the answer as correct please.

Comment: your use display:flex and text-align:center

Answer (score 0):

```css
.header {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 40px 20px;
}

.header h1 {
  background-color: yellow;
  float: left;
}

.header h1 img {
  display: block;
}

.header__nav {
  background-color: aqua;
  float: right;
}

.header__nav li {
  float: left;
  height: 38px;
}

.header__nav li a {
  padding: 0 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  <!-- Remove - line-height: 38px; -->
}

.contents {
  background-color: green;
}

.footer {
  background-color: blue;
}
<!-- new added class -->
.clearfix{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<header class="header clearfix">
  <h1>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://pixelicons.com/wp-content/themes/pexelicons/assets/pic/site-logo/logo.png" alt="Logo"></a>
  </h1>
  <nav class="header__nav">
    <ul class="clearfix">
      <li><a href="#">View icons</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Buy now</a></li>
      <li><button class="menu">menu</button></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<section class="contents">
  contents
</section>
<footer class="footer">
  footer
</footer>
```